# invalid input syntax for type json pgsql

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

This is my pgsql function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.my_func(
    data json)
    RETURNS SETOF json 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
    ROWS 1000

AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    declare _id bigint;
     _data jsonb[];
BEGIN
    _id = data::json#>>'{id}';
    _data = data::json#>>'{data}';
```

and this is how I am calling it

```
select * from my_func ('{
                         "id":"26",
                         "data":[
                            {"id":223,"title":"A"},
                            {"id":284,"title":"B","count":1495}
                         ]::jsonb[]}'::json) as info;
```

but this is showing

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
LINE 1: select * from my_func ('{
                                 ^
DETAIL:  Expected "," or "}", but found ":".
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 5: ...20","count":1495}
                         ]:...
SQL state: 22P02
Character: 26
```

How can I pass such data?

**Updte2**

I tried removing `::jsonb[]` inside the function

```
select * from my_func ('{
                         "id":"26",
                         "data":[
                            {"id":223,"title":"A"},
                        {"id":284,"title":"B","count":1495}
                         ]}'::json) as info;
```

but this shows

```
ERROR:  malformed array literal: "[
                            {"id":223,"title":"A"},
                            {"id":284,"title":"B","count":1495}
                         ]"
DETAIL:  "[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions.
```

Comment: Remove the `::jsonb[]` inside the string constant.

Comment: There are two functions shown in the question `my_func` and `tags_save`, are they actually the same?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name tried with that,i have updated the questtion

Comment: @AdrianKlaver both are same, edited the question

Comment: The last `]` inside the string should be a `}`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i missed the } , edited the question

Comment: you are passing a `json` value, so why is the variable declared as an array of `jsonb` values? `_data` should be declared as `jsonb` (or json`)